# See the location from /includes

Tags: php, php-include

I have upload my site to my server, but he can't find the folder `/includes/header.php`.
Can I echo the location where he looks to the file. The only error I see now is:
`Warning: include(/includes/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream`.

But what is the "start" location? Can I echo this?

**EDIT :**

The thing I want to know is where the location is when you use include("/blabblabla").
So the "home path"

Comment: put quotes, try `include("/includes/header.php")`;

Comment: In my code I have quotes arround it

Comment: try this include("includes/header.php");

Comment: @Thom your folder is `include` or `includes`?

Comment: Sorry, Typo mistake, the folder called includes

Comment: @Thom Do you use Linux / Unix?

Comment: `/` means starting from root directory tho

Comment: Yes, but what is the root directory from my site? Can I echo that?

Comment: Prolly starting from home if your are on linux.
U could use `getcwd()` or `__DIR__` to pinpoint the include folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**

The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php';
```

**__DIR__**

The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

```
include (__DIR__"/includes/header.php");
```

Font:  [DIR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

**getcwd()**
Gets the current working directory

```
include getcwd()."/includes/header.php";
```

Font:  [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 0):

The php include path will take a file system path as a string parameter. The path can be either absolute e.g.

```
 include('/home/yourusername/public_html/includes/somethingtoinclude.php');
```

or relative to the location of your script. So if your script is in /home/yourusername/public_html/ and your includefile is in /home/yourusername/public_html/includes/ the following will work

```
 include('includes/somethingtoinclude.php');
```

Note that include will also search in all directories in the php include path as set in php.ini in the include_path directive